# Symfony RedirectResponse Getting /code/ parameter

Tags: php, symfony

My question is: how to get 'code' parameter from the response giving by my little piece of code:

```
$clientID = "clientID...";
$clientSecret = "clientSecret...";

$url = 'https://myweb.com/oauth/authorize/?'.http_build_query(array(
'response_type' => 'code',
'client_id' => $clientID,        
'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.mywebhttp.dyndns.org/',  
'scope' => array('user')
));

$status = 302;

$response = new RedirectResponse($url,$status,$headers = array());
```

So what i see going on is that when i'm being given the response, the code parameter exists only in an url in my web explorer, so i can copy it and use. But how to get it directly from php code?
Thank you in advance!